# Single words for low degree of trust

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

I can think of *numerous* terms for varying degrees of *dis*trust: mistrust, suspicion, wariness, caution, etc; I can also think of numerous terms for very high degrees of trust: faith, confidence, conviction, etc.

However, try as I might, I can neither think of nor find any single words for varying, low degrees of *positive* trust; that is, single words which carry similar or identical meaning to phrases such as "potentially trustworthy", "moderately trusting", or "slightly trustful".

Comment: Do you have some examples?  Lando Calrissian? Benedict Arnold? A part that has operated for 40,000 cycles with a mean time to failure of 50,000 cycles?

Comment: That friend one has who usually pays back money, or the parts manufacturer that usually sends sound parts, but it's good to test them before installation. "Chaotic good" characters (in the D&D sense of the term) would also fit the bill, since you know they're generally well intentioned but it's impossible to predict exactly how they'll respond to a given situation.

Comment: "He's okay" is vaguely positive. I worked at a department store and asked a watch vendor what to say to a shopper about an awful watch he was interested in. She told me to say "It's okay."

Comment: Is "potentially trustworthy" really positive? It sounds like it means "potentially untrustworthy". Does it mean you can trust 10%, 50%, 80% of the time? "Slightly trustworthy" is even more negative. Maybe you mean someone you'd lend a book to, not necessarily expecting to get it back, which again isn't really trusting them, it's just valuing their friendship enough to risk the book.

Comment: *Hopeful* or *optimistic* suggest that you don't necessarily trust fully them but you see some possibility that they might do it. Not very hopeful about this suggestion though.

Comment: @StuartF I'm referring to any term specifically pertaining to trust, which implies a greater than neutral trust-value, but falls short of "trustworthy", "reliable", or "honest" (as examples) - all of which imply a fairly high degree of trust.

"hopeful" and "optimistic" are more about your attitude on whether or not you think they might be trustworthy, rather than the actual value you place on them currently.

Comment: I think that the phrases you offer as synonyms have different meanings. As I recall, "trustworthy" is similar to credible, while "trusting" and "trustful" are similar to credulous. In other words, they're opposites.

Answer (score 2):

**semireliable / semi-reliable** (adj.)

> (*chiefly computing*) Partly or somewhat reliable; having a fair degree
> of reliability. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semireliable)

> Words like *reliable*: **semireliable** [definition.org](https://definition.org/define/reliable/)

---

Earliest example found:

> After the fall of the glorious Icelandic Republic...the Sagas
> subsequently drifted down into only **semi-reliable** records; and later
> were little less historical than the half-fiction, half-fact of the
> Sagawriter of modern times—Sir Walter Scott. [George Browning; *The
> Edda Songs and Sagas of Iceland*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Edda_Songs_and_Sagas_of_Iceland_A_Le/YZ8-e_7f1LYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semi-reliable&pg=PA30&printsec=frontcover) (1876)

---

> I have been informed on **semireliable** authority that the irrigating
> canals of central Asia , situated in the cotton-growing districts ,
> are being very considerably extended and improved; ... [US Bureau of
> Foreign Commerce; *Special Consular Reports*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Special_Consular_Reports/eCZJAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliable&pg=PA164&printsec=frontcover) (1891)

> But until it can be procured in some reliable or **semireliable** form
> this will be impossible. [*Annual Report of the State Pathology
> Laboratory*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Annual_Report_of_the_New_York_State_Path/vgsSAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliable&pg=RA3-PA135&printsec=frontcover) p.135 (1899)

> This **semireliable** narrator is the most difficult to detect because
> he is the source of both **trustworthy and misleading information**.
> [Linda Willem; *Galdós's Segunda Manera*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Gald%C3%B3s_s_Segunda_Manera/yiFZAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=semireliable&dq=semireliable&printsec=frontcover) (1998)

> Besides, do you really want to decide whether you should remain
> married to a cheating spouse on the basis of a **semireliable** skin
> test?  [Kenneth Rosenberg; *Infidelity*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Infidelity/4_QzDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliable&pg=PT148&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

> The C18 biography itself, however, undercuts its argument for
> government sabotage by describing Donaldson's car earlier in the
> biography, calling it a “**semireliable** automobile that just about
> managed to get him from A to B” as a way of ... [Kirsten Dyck;
> *Reichsrock*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reichsrock/1hEVDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliable&pg=PT35&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> Road from Phari to Lachen/Lachung is also reported to be nearing
> completion (semi-reliable source). [Claude Arpi; *The End of an
> Era*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_End_of_an_Era_India_Exists_Tibet_Ind/oawGEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliable&pg=PT190&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

> The specification allows the user to determine whether multicast
> transfers are unreliable or **semireliable**. [Dave Kosiur; *IP
> Multicasting*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/IP_Multicasting/hsNQAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=semireliable&dq=semireliable&printsec=frontcover) (1998)

> Dennis was acting fidgety. I put him on license-plate duty. It gave
> him something to do. It gave me a **semireliable** sentry—scouring the
> passing jumble of numbers and letters for the ones we needed to rear.
> [James Siegel; *Deceit*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Deceit/4Wr0JOeIIUcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliable&pg=PT180&printsec=frontcover) (2006)

> After a documented analysis of the seven major forecasting domains,
> however, its author, William Sherden (1998) concluded that the
> forecasts that are commonly used as a basis for planning and strategy
> are only **semireliable**. [Jaap van Ginneken; *Collective Behaviour
> and Public Opinion*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Collective_Behavior_and_Public_Opinion/03WRAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliable&pg=PT376&printsec=frontcover) (2003)

> Other **semireliable** prosodic and phonological cues accompanied the
> phrasestructure grammar: word length, stress, and pitch. [Scott
> Johnson; *Neoconstructivism: The New Science of Cognitive
> Development*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Neoconstructivism/VX12CAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliable&pg=PT142&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

> Directly across two-lane Sunrise Highway Highway S1 is the start of
> Noble Canyon Trail, which strikes west–southwest only 50 yards to a
> **semireliable** water supply. [Laura Randall; *Pacific Crest Trail*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pacific_Crest_Trail_Southern_California/di7pDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliable%20water&pg=PT127&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

> A nearby spring provides a **semireliable** water source. [D. Lillard
> and G. Hicks; *Exploring the Appalachian Trail*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Exploring_the_Appalachian_Trail_Hikes_in/OYP3AQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliable%20water&pg=PT177&printsec=frontcover) (2013)

---

Should you need it, there is:

**semireliably** (adv.)

> Although absence of evidence might not be evidence of absence, the
> fact that left IFG involvement was observed only **semireliably** in
> blocked cyclic naming studies of semantic interference suggests the
> need for ... [G. de Zubicaray and N. Schiller; *The Oxford Handbook of
> Neurolinguists*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Oxford_Handbook_of_Neurolinguistics/qsGKDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliably&pg=PA489&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> Indeed, the unit pattern (that's the meme) is defined by what's
> **semireliably** copied—for example, the gene's DNA sequence is **semireliably** copied during meiosis, whereas whole chromosomes or organisms are not reliably copied at all. [William Calvin; *How Brains
> Think*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/How_Brains_Think/VBjPBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliably&pg=PT62&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> Indeed, that which is **semireliably** copied pretty much defines the
> pattern of interest.  [Diederik Aerts et al.; *Einstein Meets
> Magritte*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Einstein_Meets_Magritte_An_Interdiscipli/FuetBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliably&pg=PT241&printsec=frontcover) (2012)

---

And yes, Virginia, there is a

**semireliability** (n.)

> By World War I, submarines had advanced to the point of
> **semireliability**, but crews who found themselves trapped on the ocean floor were still doomed to drown or suffocate, for deepwater
> rescue apparatus didn't exist. [Jim Ignasher; *Rhode Island
> Disasters*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rhode_Island_Disasters/Q252CQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliability&pg=PT33&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

> Data streaming applications such as ticker tape and news feeds, which
> are one to many, need only **semireliability** sometimes and group
> sizes can be large—in the tens of thousands or even millions. [Jessica
> Keyes; *Financial Services Information Systems*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Financial_Services_Information_Systems/jUd5AgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semireliability&pg=PA419&printsec=frontcover)

---

Less common ([NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=half-reliable%2C%20semireliable&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalf%20-%20reliable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csemireliable%3B%2Cc0)) is **half-reliable (adj.)**

> The winds blow him chance bits of news in an irregular,
> **half-reliable** way. [*The Living Age*, Vol. 100, p.409](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Living_Age/H5s2AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=half-reliable&pg=PA409&printsec=frontcover) (1869)

> **Half-reliable** is simply not reliable, like a partner who tells you he or she is 50% faithful; it is a contradiction in terms.  [Michael
> Blastland; *The Hidden Half: How the World Conceals its Secrets*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Hidden_Half/xEdlDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=half-reliable&pg=PT103&printsec=frontcover)
> (2019)

---

**semi-trustworthy** (adj.) [pops up](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=semi-trustworthy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csemi%20-%20trustworthy%3B%2Cc0) once in a while.

> He then adverted to Helena, and began extolling her to the skies; but
> by this time the dwelling of his **semi-trustworthy** friend was
> visible, and reaching it they knocked him up. [Richard Bedingfield;
> *Moll Cutpurse*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Moll_Cutpurse_or_Cromwell_and_the_cavali/oxTnlt9UIbAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semi-trustworthy&pg=PA118&printsec=frontcover) (1846)

> The readers of Miss Bird's fascinating, but only **semi-trustworthy**
> work, will not be like to read Mr. Dickson's comely volume. [*The
> Literary World*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Literary_World/e6k5AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semi-trustworthy&pg=PA283&printsec=frontcover) (1889)

> I have tried to disentangle from a mass of only **semi-trustworthy**
> records the true origin of the well-known saying: "He has Seius' Horse
> in his stable." [Basil Tozer; *The Horse in History*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Horse_in_History/FRFFAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semi-trustworthy&pg=PA27&printsec=frontcover) (1908)

> However in many cases the organization may be semi-honest or
> completely dishonest. In the case of **semi-trustworthy** (also called
> semi-honest) partners, organizations may have to play games to extract
> data. [H. Chen and C. Yang; *Intelligence and Security
> Informatics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Intelligence_and_Security_Informatics/rn1rCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=semi-trustworthy&pg=PA10&printsec=frontcover) (2008)

---

You can also mix and match—you'll find **half-trustworthy** as well.

Comment: I'd expect ngrams of 'not very reliable' and 'fairly reliable' to outperform 'semireliable' by quite a distance, but the word does exist.

Comment: Sometimes you gotta jump through hoops for a single-word request :-) You can also go off the grid completely: I found *reliable(ish), reliable-ish,* and *reliable'ish*.

Comment: After looking at the number and dates of Google Book examples, I think *semireliably* could go mainstream in dictionaries, especially because you can reliably write it without a hyphen.

Comment: This is the closest thing I've seen to an answer, but 'reliable' and 'trustworthy' have somewhat different connotations:

"The engine is only semireliable; I only <target word> the engine."

That example more or less distinguishes what I'm looking for from what you've suggested.

And as I pointed out elsewhere, if one begins making ad hoc qualifications to words, the sky is the limit: 'pseudo-', 'quasi-', 'semi-', 'half-', 'micro-', 'pre-', or even 'iX-' (the whole 'i' family of latin prefixes) could all be used in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think of one single word, but would use "some trust" (or some faith, confidence, etc.).  This is used to imply less than total trust, but not distrust.  Or "a moderate degree of trust" (or of faith, confidence, etc.), explicitly saying not a high degree but not a low degree either.

Comment: Yes, qualifiers permit the expression of any degree of trust one can imagine, but single-word terms seem to be elusive.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my hat into the ring . . . Have you considered "reputable"? It suggests that the person can be trusted but is not exactly a very enthusiastic endorsement.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use the term 'anecdotal' to imply that the conclusion or premise is based upon personal experience and not objective evidence.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For a relationship, **arm’s length** might be appropriate.

https://legaldictionary.net/arms-length/

The basic idea in an arm’s length relationship is that the parties have no prior relationship, and no way of judging each other’s reliability, save by their general expectation based on past experience.

The term is commonly used in tax law.